# Python/numpy : How to tweek nested loops to speed the code

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Imagine a Numpy `np.array` of shape N,C,K,H,W
and
`meanCoeffs = np.mean(x, axis=(3,4))` of shape N,C,K

```
import time
import numpy as np

def func(j1,t1,L):
    return t1+j1*L


N,C,J,L,H,W = 128,5,3,8,64,64
x = np.random.rand(N,C,J*L,H,W)
meanCoeffs = np.mean(x, axis=(3,4))
xnew=np.zeros_like(x)

start = time.time()
for ib in range(x.shape[0]):
    for filt in range(x.shape[1]):
        for j1 in range(J):
            for t1 in range(L):
                i=func(j1,t1,L)
                xnew[ib,filt,i,:,:] = x[ib,filt,i,:,:]-meanCoeffs[ib,filt,i]
end = time.time()
print ("Time elapsed:", end - start)
```

Time elapsed: 0.18448996543884277

Note that the `func` function can be complicated.

Is there a way to speed up this crude code?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  Your posted code doesn't run as given.  It seems that you're looking for an algorithm review with respect to NumPy usage; is that correct?  If so, then you're perhaps better suited for CodeReview than here.

Answer (score 0):

The indexing in

```py
for j1 in range(J):
    for t1 in range(L):
       i=t1+j1*L
```

is equivalent to simply saying

```
for i in range(J*L):
```

That is, the three loops boil down to a loop over all three indices, and the subtraction is a simple broadcast:

```
xnew2 = x - meanCoeffs[:, :, :, None, None]
```

If you prefer, you could also use `np.expand_dims(meanCoeffs, (3, 4))`.

You can verify that this is the same you're doing on your concrete example:

```
In [14]: np.all(xnew == xnew2)
Out[14]: True
```

Comment: Ha, when updating my post, I discard a remark: the loops j1,t1 cannot be collapsed as the 'i'-index is a function of j1,t1 that I have just simplyfied.

Comment: In that case, the post does not accurately reflect the generality of the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: What is `func` in practice? As stated, it suffices to determine the image of `func`, which may or may not be easier than calculating it explicitly. Is it always going to be injective? If so, the code once again boils down to subtracting over all dimensions at one.